# current_user method is not accessible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, declarative-authorization

i am using **declarative_authorization**... when i try to access **current_user**, it gives me the error **undefined local variable or method `current_user'**... can anyone help me out..?

thnx...

Comment: Would help to know where you are trying to access it from. Model, view, controller, helper?

Comment: @shadwell.... from all of them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`current_user` is a method that has to be provided *for* declarative authorization, not something it provides.

From the [read me](http://github.com/stffn/declarative_authorization):

> Requirement:
>
> An authentication mechanism
>
> - User object in Controller#current_user
> - (For model security) Setting Authorization.current_user

There is also a section in that read me also about providing the requirements using restful authentication to provide the `current_user` functionality.

Comment: Hey Shadwell, do you think you could look into my problem I am having with decl_auth too please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631218/how-do-i-access-a-user-with-a-specific-role-in-rails-3